# Does soul collection conflict with item collection?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was farming in The King's Passage using the Jester's Hat and the Covetous Gold Serpent Ring +1, but at the same time I had the Jester's Gloves and the Covetous Silver Serpent's Ring +2 on as well to boost my soul collection. I was also consuming Rusted Coins with every run to help boost the item find rate.

After all 7 runs (the enemies had stopped spawning) all I had found was one Stone Parma and a set of Llewelyn Leggings. That's pretty terrible considering the last few times I ran through there I managed to get at least 4 shields, 2 armour sets, 2 stone twin blades and 3 titanite slabs.

Is it possible that my soul farming gear was interfering with my item farming gear?

Comment: I don't think so. Kings passage is kind of a crappy place to farm IMO. What were you trying to get?

Comment: Whatever was available. Mainly the Llewelyn set. But like I said, my latest attempt was a very big contrast from previous attempts.

Comment: I have read rumors where sometimes drop rate is actually lowered when stacking jester, gold serpent ring, and rusted coins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, no I don't think so.

I used to farm Desert Sorceress Top (you know how popular that thing is). If stories from Reddit is to be believed, some people experienced extreme trouble in obtaining it, I got one when I was wearing both Silver Serpent and Gold Serpent. In practice I pretty much never take off the soul farming ring, and I only wear my item farming ring when I'm trying to farm, got quite a few good items that way

Most probably, you're just being extremely unlucky